# How to use parent JSP variables in a JSP javascript injected children?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, jsp

Hi everyone I'm working in a Spring MVC application with JSP, my problem is in a certain moment I make a controller request to get a pice of JSP code for be included in a div. I get the JSP code from a ModelAndView answer. I put it my div by JQuery. but when I want to use my JSP container variables I can't do it. I'll show my code.

**JSP Container (parent)**

```
                <div class="row" id="principalDiv">
                <div id="menuZone">
                    <c:forEach items="${user.rol.permisos}" var="permisos">


                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2 iconos methodDiv" id="${permisos.permisoMetodoMap}">
                            <div>

                                <center>
                                    <i class="fa <c:out value="${permisos.permisoMetodoIcono}" /> fa-5x" id="icon_${permisos.permisoMetodoMap}"></i>
                                </center>
                                <br>
                                <center>
                                    <div>
                                        <c:out value="${permisos.permisoNombre}" />
                                    </div>
                                </center>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </c:forEach>
                </div>

                <div id="loadZone">
            </div>

        </div>
```

Whit a button I made a reques to my controller, to get the content for "loadZone".

**Code JSP request**

```
function loadAsp(element) {
    $.get('getInclude', {
        include : $(element).attr('id')
    }, function(responseText) {
        $('#loadZone').html(responseText);
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/getInclude")
public class IncludesDispatcherController {

    @Autowired
    FormModelBo boConsultas;
    @GetMapping
public ModelAndView getReportesView() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("includes/reportes");
        try {
            mav.addObject("consultas", boConsultas.consultaGeneral());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mav;

    }

}
```

I return the view with a model to make a title table and that can see in the above JQuery fragment I put the view in the div with html() method.

**JSP to be include (children)**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>

        <div>
            <center>
                <legend>
<!--                //<img alt="" src="img/pen.png"> -->
                    Censo M&eacute;tricas Triage ${user.nombre}<br />  <--- this is parent variable.
                </legend>
            </center>
        </div>
        <form action="${user.rol.rolMap}/createExcel" method="POST" role="form" id="">

            <div class="form-group">

                <!-- -------------------------------------------first section--------------------------- -->
                <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 22px !important;">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-group ">
                                <div class="input-group ">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Fecha inicio</span> <input type="date" id="fecha_1" name="fecha_1" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-group ">
                                <div class="input-group ">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">Fecha final</span> <input type="date" id="fecha_2" name="fecha_2" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Generar Reporte</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>


        <div style="padding-bottom: 22px !important;">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre de médico</th>
                        <th>Número de consultas</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <c:forEach items="${consultas}" var="consultasLista">
                        <tr>
                            <td><c:out value="${consultasLista[0]} ${consultasLista[1]} ${consultasLista[2]}" /></td>
                            <td><c:out value="${consultasLista[3]}" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
```

the model variables that i send in my ModelAndView are working but my parent didn't.

I try with other methods like declare variblaes

```
<%
String variable = "test";
%>
```

or

```
request.setAttribute("attrName", myValue); (for catch it in my children JSP with request.getAttribute())
```

but not works too. I don't know if it 'cause JSP parent code is alredy compiled. I need access to my parent variables.

Please help me and thanks for the time.

Comment: JSP-code runs at the server. I don't know where you get 'JSP to be include' from, but if you send this code as shown via ajax-answer to the browser, there is no one who can do `<c:forEach` or `<c:out`

Answer (score 0):

If you need variable **${user.nombre}** in IncludesDispatcherController you need to inject it to this controller and then to the view, otherwise it will be null.

Anyway, like someone already mention JSP is serverside language and your interaction with javascript and Ajax is not really perfect. It's much better aproach if you don't send directly HTML but for instance just use JSON to send data which javascript need.

After that it would be much better if you use the data, that you already have in your parent - *"${user.rol.permisos}"*. You can put it in "data-" tag and then easily read by JQuery. In your loop, you can do something like this:

```
<a href="#" id="icon_1" data-nombre="${permisos.permisoNombre}">
```

And read it by this:

```
$("a#icon_1" ).data("nombre");
```